# Xcode - iOS: symbols won't get exported in a static library

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, ld

For the life of me i can NOT get a static library to export its symbols!  At least that's what other client code linking to it says (undefined symbols for architecture armv7).

Here are my project settings:

- Perform a single-object pre link = yes
- Deployment postprocessing = yes
- Other linker flags = -ObjC -all_load
- Strip Debug Symbols During Copy = No
- Strip Linked Product = No
- Strip Style = Non-Global Symbols

The only thing left for me to try is to use a symbol export file, but i just don't want to do that because i must be missing something so obvious and i have *many* more static libs and frameworks to build.

Any advice, *please*.  I wasted soooo much time.  Thanks!

Comment: How about: "Dead Code Stripping" => No (for all settings)?

Comment: Maybe try removing -Objc and/or -all_load and see how it reacts?

Comment: I tried both suggestions : nothing happened

Comment: what architectures are in your .a file - plz check with lipo